# JavaFx | Intellij : Create elevated application

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm creating a Windows application using `JavaFx` and `Intellij-idea`, Some of the functions are executing CMD command. One of the command is `route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0` which will block the machine from using internet connection, but since the command was no right of administrator the result is `The requested operation requires elevation.`

So, I'm thinking maybe it will solve the problem if I can make the application elevated by setting it up in Intellij-idea.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/native/WinElevator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState\"");` or you could also make a shortcut to an admin command prompt shortcut and call that